# Glassfish session replication not working

Tags: java, jsp, glassfish-3, session-replication

I'm struggling with making a simple app replicate it session. The thing is very basic. At first I've setuped two VMs to do this but with no luck so I thinked that maybe I'll do it on a single machine and so I did.

I've create a cluster with two instances both on the same machine. Marked the 'availability' checkbox while deploying so it would acctually replicate the session.

I've also made changes to my code that were given on some oracle man webpage:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <distributable id="sessionDistribute" />
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

sun-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 9.0 
Servlet 2.5//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_2_5-0.dtd">


<sun-web-app>
    <session-config>
        <session-manager persistence-type="replicated">
            <manager-properties>
                <property name="persistenceFrequency" value="web-method"/>
            </manager-properties>
            <store-properties>
                <property name="persistenceScope" value="session"/>
            </store-properties>
        </session-manager>
        <session-properties/>
        <cookie-properties/>
    </session-config>
</sun-web-app>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.util.Enumeration"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Session Form</h1>

<%
    if (request.getParameter("sessionName") != null && request.getParameter("sessionValue") != null) {
        HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();
        httpSession.setAttribute(request.getParameter("sessionName"), request.getParameter("sessionValue"));
    }
%>

<form action="index.jsp" method="POST">

    your session name : <input type="text" name="sessionName" /> <br />
    your session value : <input type="text" name="sessionValue" /> <br />
    <input type="submit" />

</form>

<h1>Your Sessions</h1>

<%
    Enumeration sessionNames = session.getAttributeNames();
    while (sessionNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String mySessionName = sessionNames.nextElement().toString();
        String mySession = request.getSession().getAttribute(mySessionName).toString();
        out.print(mySessionName+ " --> "+mySession + " <br />");
    }
%>

</body>
</html>
```

When I post something into the session it does not occure on the secon instance.
I've been fighting with this the second day and I'm running out of idea...

Any tips would be grea.

Comment: hi, do you have any update on this issue? I am fighting the same problem.. Thanks!

Comment: I'm too have some problem

Comment: If it's still of any help, restarting glassfish is needed. Also check if your multicast works between the two nodes.

Comment: I'm having the same probleme, new session id is created in each request!